# making this pythonic

Tags: python

How can I make the following snipped of code "pythonic"

```
 tag_list = []
 for d in docs:
        tags = d["tags"]
        for tag in tags:
            if tag not in tag_list:
                tag_list.append(tag)
```

Comment: I don't write Python code, but judging from the answers below, "Pythonic" is apparently a synonym for "obfuscated".  I had no problem understanding your code, the other snippets took some thinking.

Comment: @EdS. Strongly disagree. Python is intended to enable declarative programming; writing an expression that describes the set you want to end up with is far simpler and easier to read than code that walks through the (a possible) process for assembling it. Also, pretty much anything that invokes `set` here will be far, far faster than anything that doesn't for sufficiently large and redundant input.

Comment: Actually, on further reflection, I suppose it's *non*-redundant input where a pure list-based approach gets slow (since the repeated checks for a redundant value are against a larger number of candidates).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
taglist = set()
for d in docs:
    taglist |= set(d["tags"])
taglist = list(taglist)
```

or

```
from itertools import chain
taglist = list(set(chain(*(d["tags"] for d in docs))))
```

or (thx to @lazy1):

```
from itertools import chain
taglist = list(set(chain.from_iterable(d["tags"] for d in docs)))
```

or

```
import operator
taglist = list(reduce(operator.or_, (set(d["tags"]) for d in docs)))
```

Comment: For the 2'nd solution you can use chain.from_iterable

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: (blink) I would not have expected .union to work on non-sets, but I see it does. You can remove the inner parentheses from set(), though. You really ought to submit it as an answer.

Comment: @HughBothwell I think I shall. As for `set(())`, I was fixated on how the `repr` of an empty set is `set([])`.

Answer (score 10):

In 3.x (and possibly 2.7, I don't remember), you can do a set comprehension:

```
tag_list = {tag for doc in docs for tag in doc["tags"]}
```

In 2.x, you can build a set from a generator expression:

```
tag_list = set(tag for doc in docs for tag in doc["tags"])
```

After that, if you really need it as a list, just do `list(tag_list)`.

Comment: 2.7 provides set comprehensions, yes.

Answer (score 2):

`help(set.union)` tells us

```
Help on method_descriptor:

union(...)
    Return the union of sets as a new set.

    (i.e. all elements that are in either set.)
```

What isn't explicit is that you can pass any number of arguments and everything will be union'd together (presumably the implementation shares code with `set.update`, help for which refers to "union of itself and others"). What isn't mentioned at all, but is true, is that the arguments can be any iterables, not just other sets. This makes sense if you think about the algorithm; there isn't really a way to merge two sets that's any better than just iterating over one and adding each element to the other.

Accordingly, we can do the job with the amazingly simple and descriptive:

```
list(set().union(*(d['tags'] for d in docs)))
```

This is a bit more explicit than `itertools.chain`ing arguments together for the `set` constructor (which doesn't accept `*args`), making it my preference.

(I also really like the nested set comprehension approach, although the way nested comprehensions works takes a little getting used to.)